# Sendmail Bounced Mail Body

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, email, centos, sendmail

I currently administer a CentOS 5 web server (apache), for which mail can be sent to different users via a web form. These users receiving the email are external to this server and not something I have control over.

I have edited `/etc/aliases` to send all of root's email to my external email address using:

```
root: me@myemail.com
```

Occasionally I will get a bounced message, but it won't send me what the actual message is. I just get:

> Your message did not reach some or all
>   of the intended recipients.

With the subject included and stating that the email address doesn't exist. I would like to track down the recipients and forward them the bounced message. Is there any way I can see the body of the original messages that were sent? The email server is sendmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your mail server is not generating the bounce.  The receiving mail server is.  It's up to the receiving mail server to include the message in the bounce.  Most mail admins won't include the message because it just opens them up to being a [backscatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_%28e-mail%29) relay.
Your only option as I see it, would be to contact the mail admins for each user and ask them to include the message in the bounce if your domain is the source...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any information in /var/log/maillog?